# Отобразить комментарии клиентов на главной страницы

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Моя задача отобразить комментарии пользователей на главной страницы. И желательно также отобразить продукт, к которому были оставлены комментарии.

Когда я отображаю в форме следующий код:

View -> form

```
<h2>What others felt about this:<h2>
      <% @product.reviews.reverse.each do |review|%>
      <p> <%= review.content%>
      Posted <%=time_ago_in_words(review.created_at)%> ago by
      <%=review.client.name%></p>
```

то все отлично работает. 
Далее покажу пару методов в данном классе:
Reviews controller:

```
def create
       @product =Product.find params[:product_id]
       @review = @product.reviews.new(review_params)
       @review.client_id = @current_client.id
       @review.save


       respond_to do |format|
       format.html {redirect_to @product}
       end
   end

private
   def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:content, :product_id, :client_id, :stars)
   end
```

Но когда я на главной страничке пытаюсь отобразить данные комментарии:

```
<div class="item active">


  <% @product.reviews.reverse.each do |review|%>
  <p> <%= review.content%>
  Posted <%=time_ago_in_words(review.created_at)%> ago by
  <%=review.client.name%></p>


  </div>
```

**То говорится что review = nil.** 
Ошибка:
    undefined method `reviews' for nil:NilClass

Что мне нужно изменить, чтобы отобразить комментарий на главной страницы и желательно картинку продукта. `product.picture`

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Поставил минус за очередное "отладьте мой код за меня, пожалуйста". Пользуйтесь отладчиком! Выясняйте, везде ли именно те объекты, которые вы ожидаете! Но если уж просите помощи, по возможности (а здесь она явно есть) **цитируйте** сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Процитировала сообщение. думала просто что из моего комментария ошибка понятна. Просто я не понимаю почему этот метод не виден, если в форме он виден и работает хорошо.

Comment: О да. Вот поэтому я и просил сообщение. `nil` не `review`. А то, у чего вызывается `reviews`, т. е. `@product`. И я действительно не вижу в вопросе кода, который задаёт его для главной.

Comment: в этом у меня путаница. почему в форме все в порядке с reviews, а на главной - нет

Comment: Потому что на главной не задан `@product`, очевидно.

Comment: Дело в том, что я действительно не знаю/не понимаю как на главное странице задать все это. Потому что это не форма. В связи с этим я и задала вопрос. как сделать так, чтобы ничего не выдавало - nil, когда я помещаю это на главную страницу!

Comment: *Потому что это не форма.* -- Хе, а как вы задаёте `@product` для формы?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю - методом create в products_controller

Comment: *\*вздыхает** Нет, не там. Перед тем, как продолжать, вам явно нужно ознакомиться с самыми основами Ruby on Rails, с понимания того где в них модель, контроллер и представление и как они связаны между собой.

Comment: Окей, в то же время в models, в database, когда создавала scaffold для products. Получается, что у меня есть данные в трех составляющих model-view-controller: и все данные внесены во все части. Но не отображаются на главной страницы из-за того, что я что-то упускаю. Пыталась просто узнать - что.

Comment: Судя по тому, что я вижу сейчас, вы совершенно упускаете, какой код из контроллера исполняется и в какой момент, а именно в контроллерах размещается сама суть происходящего. И, повторяя совет из первого комментария, настоятельно рекомендую вооружиться каким-нибудь отладчиком для Ruby, лично я пользуюсь [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/).

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определите переменную **@product** в экшене контроллера вашей главной страницы и все будет работать. Сейчас @product - nil.